# Algolia InstantSearch Swift Package Manager throws Compile error

Tags: ios, xcode, algolia, swift-package-manager, instantsearch

I am trying to integrate InstantSearch Library via Swift Package Manager.

However, I get this error while compiling:

> error: The package product ‘AlgoliaSearchClient’ requires minimum platform version 14.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 12.0 (in target ‘InstantSearchCore’ from project ‘InstantSearch’)

**Note :** All our targets supports minimum deployments target of 14 and more.

[Please see the screenshot of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUzEq.jpg).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error message has it right - you’ll need to raise the iOS version target to 14.0 in the Xcode project settings to use that package.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using Neeraj? I'm having the same issue with this library since I updated to 15.3

Comment: I got a reply from Algolia's Support team. They suggested this : "Here is a workaround you may consider, by manually adding github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift to your project, and setting the resolution rule to be exact: 8.19.0." Please also refer : github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios/issues/305

Comment: Hi @Alec. I am using Xcode 15.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think there is an issue with the latest version of this package. To resolve in the meantime I have rolled mine back to use v8.19.0 as below which seems to work.

[image: Changes]

Comment: I got a reply from Algolia's Support team.
They suggested this :
"Here is a workaround you may consider, by manually adding https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift to your project, and setting the resolution rule to be exact: 8.19.0."
Please also refer : https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios/issues/305

Answer (score 1):

Swift packages have a minimum iOS deployment target. In the case of this package it only supports iOS 14.0 and higher.

Your Xcode project has a deployment target of 12.0. You’ll need to raise it to 14.0 in order to use this package.

You can make this change in the Project settings General tab.

Comment: Hey Chris, All our targets supports minimum deployments target of 14 and more.

Comment: That’s strange then, as the error suggests that the `InstantSearchCore` target supports version 12.0. If that’s not the case I’m unsure what to try next.